# how to run all the API's in thread which will fetch the first value from CSV after one iteration it should fetch the second value from csv

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a script which has Login API which fetch the first values from CSV file after other API's run which should run with the same user, after running all the API in thread again it should fetch the second value from csv.
I have done with the entire setup but while running the script it's randomly fetch the value from csv

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using multiple Thread Group. if yes then look for sharing mode in CSV Data Set Config. link with help you to understand sharing mode
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy

For Single Thread Group use sharing mode as **Current thread** in CSV Data Set Config

Comment: Thanks rohan for reply, I have single thread group in which many API included, Now I want to run all the api with first user from csv then after running all the apis next second value should be fetch from csv for all the api in thread

Comment: ok. then set sharing mode as : **Current thread** under CSV Data Set Config

Comment: Still it is not accepting first value for all the api, for each api it is fetching different values from csv file

Comment: @Rock will need more info. if possible can you share screenshot of your jmeter test. it will be easy to understand the issue.